# Arrangements with 2 restrictions and "at least"

Tags: combinatorics

How many different arrangements can we have for the the word I-S-O-S-C-E-L-E-S if we must have at least 2 S's be adjacent and both E's must be adjacent?

I decided to count up all the cases that aren't what I want since doing anything involving "at least" any other way is a hassle. Starting with S's, laying out all the letters and a space in between as a divider for each letter, I get

_ I_O_C_E_L_E _ which gives me 7 spaces Choose 3 = 35 combs where all S's are separated

Then I took to counting all instances where the E's are separated to get:

_ I_O_C_L _ giving me 5 spaces and 2 E's = 5 spaces choose 3 = 10.

Lastly we count the arrangements for the remaining 4 letters to get 4!. Now we subtract the total number of arrangements from (number of possibilities with no adjacent S's)*(number of possibilities with no adjacent E's)*(number of remaining arrangements) to get:

$\frac{9!}{3!*2!} - 35*10*4! = 21,840$

I don't think this is correct because the number it would be if I just had the restriction for S's would be $\frac{9!}{3!*2!}-35*6!=5,040$ so adding another restriction that the E's have to be adjacent should not have caused the number of possibilities to have increased. Adding restrictions is supposed to decrease them, so I'm almost certain something is incorrect here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple way.

First consider $I,O,C,L,\boxed{SS},\boxed{EE}$ permuted in $6!$ ways

The extra $S$ can be inserted in only *six* ways instead of possible seven, because you can only insert it on one side of $\boxed{SS}$ to avoide overcounting.

Thus $6!*6 = 4320$

Comment: So blocking together the repeats but excluding the third S and adding it on later? I didn't know I could do it this way. So by putting the letter S on the left or the right, it's actually not 2 separate possibilities bc the order does not matter, right? If it were S,S, and s, and the restriction was that the 2 S's had to be adjacent and s on either side, then it would be 7 spaces, correct?

Comment: Yes, if there were two $S$ and one $s$ it would be $6!\times 7$ following the procedure in the answer. Of course, it could now be instead done more simply as just $7!$

Answer (score 3):

Consider "ee" and "ss" to be a single letter each; So I, SS, O, C, EE, L, S is a 7-letter word with 7 different letters. As such it has 7! = 5040 permutations.

However, the permutations with three consecutive S, such as ISSSOCEEL, have been counted twice, because it can be S immediately followed by SS or SS immediately followed by S. There are 6! = 720 permutations with three consecutive S.

Thus the final number of permutations that you should count is 7! - 6! = 4320.

---

We can verify our math with a python program that bruteforce-enumerates all permutations of ISOSCELES, and removes the unwanted ones:

```
from itertools import permutations

perms = {''.join(s) for s in permutations('isosceles')}
good_perms = [w for w in perms if 'ss' in w and 'ee' in w]

print(len(good_perms))
# 4320
```